# Impact of deleting 100GB table on Mirroring

Tags: sql-server-2008, mirroring

I'm about to delete a large table which is approximately 100GB in size.  I'd like to understand the impact on the mirroring that's in place on this db.  Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I might be inclined to turn mirroring off, then drop the table, and then re-initialize mirroring from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question such that you want to `DROP` that table, not `DELETE FROM T` it.

That is a metadata-only operation and completes almost instantly on both instances. The page deallocations generate *some* load but certainly nothing like deleting 100GB of rows.

Answer (score 2):

What is type of mirroring Sync or Async

Yes there would be impact and impact would be in terms of amount of transaction log being generated. Delete logs each row which is being deleted so logging will be heavy. Your approach should be to delete in batches this would minimize lock escalation, blocking and thus would not hamper concurrency much. You should also consider performing this activity when load is relatively less

How strong is your network connecting principal and mirror. You are going to put heavy load on it if you delete 100G table so becareful with that aspect also its good to ask network team to have a look on network during this period of time you would not like your mirror to lag behind principal.

Can you truncate the tables or selectively truncate tables, it is super quick and logging is very very less as compared to delete but *NOTE* there are limitations with truncate table and before proceeding please read below Microsoft documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177570.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response. The operating mode is high performance Async.  I thought if I deleted the table in the primary it would just be a ddl statement on the mirror site? In your opinion then a truncate is much more efficient than a delete for mirroring?

Comment: Well Async mirroring will give you relief in tems of commit on primary. It will not wait for mirror to commit and so if you have timely transaction  log jobs they would truncate logs more efficiently if nothing is holding logs. And If you are Ok with truncate statement well thats best you can do.